# PHP Session Variable gets lost between pages.

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have made a simple login page to access an application. The login works fine at times, but from time to time, I'll have trouble logging into the system, as the session data will be lost on the last page.

The files I have are 
1) login.php, with Login name and Password Field.

2) loginprocess.php - Which will connect to the database to check whether there username and password exists, after which a session is created.

3) listing.php - Which will be the final page if login is successful.

The loginprocess.php page will create a session variable if Login Name and Password exists in the database. It'll then redirect to the last page.

```
$selectstring = "SELECT * FROM logintable WHERE username='".$loginname."' AND password='".$pass."'";
$result = mysql_query($selectstring);

//IF YES THEN GO TO MAIN
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 //CREATE SESSION   
session_start();
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["loginname"]= $loginname;     
header("Location: listing.php");
exit;

}
else { 
echo "ERROR";
header("Location: login.php?message=error");
exit;
}
```

At the top of the last page, listing.php, I'll have a script that will redirect if session variable is empty.

```
session_start(); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['loginname']) && empty($_SESSION['loginname'])) {
   header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Am I inserting session_start(); too late on loginprocess.php ?

Comment: Why _session_start();_ multiple times ?

Comment: Please write `session_start();` at the top of your page not inside your while loop

Comment: remove _echo "ERROR";_ from else part

Comment: `session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
]);` - you can use this to control your time on the session also. Note: `header(Location: xxxx)` should contain `exit;` after them.

Comment: don't use mysql its removed from PHP7

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: `header("Location: login.php");` should be followed by `exit;`

Answer (score 1):

First, move the `session_start();` to the top of your file.

Next, you need to do an OR instead of an AND in your `if`, because the login name is either unset *or* empty.